# Microsoft HPC: mixing windows and linux blades

Tags: linux, windows, hpc

I have a working Windows HPC cluster with 32 blades, all of them are using **Windows HPC**. 
My question is: **can I install Linux on 16 blades** and keep the other 16 on Windows? Is there a specific version of Linux that I can use?

**update**
What would I like to know is: does the headnode (which is a Windows HPC machine) could submit the jobs to those nodes? I was thinking that Ms may have released some kind of kernel modules to let Linux integrate with his HPC infrastructure.

Comment: Which version of Windows HPC server? I found these documents referencing Server 2008 http://blogs.technet.com/b/windowshpc/archive/2008/10/02/integrating-windows-hpc-server-2008-with-linux.aspx

Comment: I've got to ask, though. Why would *want* to? I could understand if you were integrating an existing system, but if you have a working HPC cluster, why do you want to complicate and potentially bring in all sorts of compatibility nightmares?

Comment: Good question. We use our cluster to perform data analysis with large dataset and some of our researcher use software which is only available on Linux platforms. Thanks for the link

Comment: I know this seems off topic but our companies BI guys used to use both linux based and windws hpc based clusters with large datasets but lately they've been testing http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/hdinsight/ its only preview mode but seems to work quite nicely and integrates well with MS's stuff..